# Bluemix: Are devops services available on Bluemix local?

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops

Does the Bluemix local provide devops services like Delivery Pipeline and Active Deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluemix Local includes a private syndicated catalog that displays the local services that are available exclusively to you. It also includes additional services that are made available to you to use from Bluemix Public. The syndicated catalog provides the function to create hybrid applications that consist of public and private services.

Bluemix Local comes with all included Bluemix runtimes and a set of services and components available. Take a look at the Table 1. Local Services in [Bluemix Local Docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html#local).

As you can see, for example the Auto-Scaling service is already included in the local environment. However you have the option to decide which public services meet the requirements for your business based on your data privacy and security criteria.